# Crontab: schedules jobs ran in infinite loop get stuck

Tags: bash, cron

I have the following code performed at reboot of my server

```
@reboot root cd /home/scripts && for f in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -name . \)`; do eval $f & \;;done
```

So basically I want to run all scripts located in scripts directory as background tasks

Each of these are infinite scripts (while true; do )

I noticed though that some scripts get "stuck", so I have to reboot the server to keep them going (By using **ps -aux** I see that some scripts are being performed, while others have outdated timestamp, so they are stuck)

Any solution to that?

Comment: fix the problems with the scripts.

Comment: there are no problems. Just over the time eventually some would stuck

Comment: Getting "stuck" sounds like a problem. But... I'm not clear what you mean by "outdated timestamp". Do you mean the time they were started? If so, that's not supposed to update.